# How can I make table header cells both bold and underline in python?

Tags: python, python-docx

I am creating a table using python 3.4 and I would like to make the header both bold and underline. The following code will make the header bold:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run('Date Filmed:').bold = True
hdr_cells[2].paragraphs[0].add_run('Barcode Number:').bold = True
```

If I change the 3rd line to:

```
hdr_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run('Date Filmed:').underline = True
```

it will make the text underlined, but not bold. It there a way to make the text of the header both bold and underlined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add boolean run properties one at a time

```
run = hdr_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run('Date Filmed:')
run.bold = True
run.underline = True
```

Comment: I suppose, [python-docx] tag should be added

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open a word document and create there a new table template. In this template you can e.g. set the first row as bold and underlined.

Load this document with the table template:

```
document = Document('doc_with_table_template.docx')
```

Add a table with this style:

```
table_positionen = document.add_table(3, 2))
table_positionen.style = 'YOUR TEMPLATE NAME'
```

Add the text in it:

```
hdr_cells = table_positionen.rows[0].cells
for i in range(2): # cols
        pa = hdr_cells[i].paragraphs[0].add_run("Hello")
        pa.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
```

With this you can also set the alignments if needed.